# How to get html in controller posted from view using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to post some HTML from my view to a controller using AJAX. However I don't know how to get the posted HTML in the controller.

```
var form = $('.Container').html();

$.ajax({
  url: "/Public/Support",
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  contentType: "test/plain",
  dataType: "html",
  data: { form: form },
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.Result == false) {
    } else {
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: `public ActionResult Support(string form) { ...` However, sending HTML is a bit of a code smell. It would make more sense to send a data structure which can be stored more efficiently, and then turn that back in to HTML when needed by your front-end.

Comment: form comes as null in controller

Answer (score 0):

By default html, content is disabled from posting to the server due to security reasons( [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks and HTML injection attacks), You have to allow by using an attribute from data annotation.

** Model:**

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
 }

 above will allow HTML content to post, however, if you are saving this content to 
database save it encoded and retrieve as it is and display by decoding it 


var form = $('.Container').html();

 $.ajax({
   url: "/Public/Support",
   type: 'POST',
   cache: false,
   contentType: "test/plain",
   dataType: "html",
   data: { form: htmlEntities(form) },
   success: function (data) {
   if (data.Result == false) {
      } else {
    }
  },
 });


 function htmlEntities(str) {
     return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, 
    '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  }    /// you can reverse this funtion to decode to display
```

or maybe you can use different encoding and decoding techniques on the server side also

Comment: what about the controller?

Comment: @RezaMakvandi try with the current controller